# $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,$attachment); in the new php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For publishing stream in the old php sdk we used :

`$facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message,$attachment);`

Now I want to accomplish it in the new version of php sdk which doesn't support api_client but instead uses

`$facebook -> api(\\an array\\);`

I have tried a lot to modify it myself but in vain.

Comment: http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=214 nice tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an array you will call the REST API anyway so you can stick to what you currently have. However, if you want to I think you could try something like

```
facebook->api(array('method' => 'stream_publish', 'message' => 'test message', 'attachment' => 'attachment details'));
```

Nonetheless, I suggest you use a proper Graph API method which is described here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/ and works well.